# How to round a floating point number upto 3 digits after decimal point in bash

Tags: bash, floating-point, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I am a new `bash` learner. I want to print the result of an expression given as input having `3 digits` after decimal point with rounding if needed.
I can use the following code, but it does not round. Say if I give `5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7` as input for the following code, the given output is `17.928`. Actual result is `17.92857...`. So, it is *truncating* instead of **rounding**. I want to round it, that means the **output should be** `17.929`. My code:

```
read a
echo "scale = 3; $a" | bc -l
```

Equivalent `C++` code can be(in `main` function):

```
float a = 5+50*3.0/20.0 + (19*2.0)/7.0;
cout<<setprecision(3)<<fixed<<a<<endl;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I think if you divide the number by 1 then it will scale the number. `echo "scale = 3; $a / 1" | bc -l`

Comment: @ooga, sorry, it does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about

```
a=`echo "5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7" | bc -l`
a_rounded=`printf "%.3f" $a`
echo "a         = $a"
echo "a_rounded = $a_rounded"
```

which outputs

```
a         = 17.92857142857142857142
a_rounded = 17.929
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:
Here bc will provide the bash the functionality of caluculator and -l will read every single one in string and finally we are printing only three decimals at end

```
read num
echo $num | bc -l | xargs printf "%.3f"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", (5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7)}'
17.929
```

`%.3f` output format will round up the number to 3 decimal points.

Comment: It works fine for this string. But how to implement it if I take the string as input? You can see [this](https://ideone.com/rdnWmd) what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two simple solutions:

```
read input 
var=$(echo "scale=4; $input" | bc) 
printf "%.3f\n" "$var"
```

and the second one is simpler:

```
printf "%.3f" $(cat - |bc -l)
```

where

> **cat -** reads numeric value from input.

> **|** pipes the input to the next command.

> **bc -l** performs needed calculations.

> **(...)** captures the output.

> **printf "%.3f"** formats and prints the captured output as a floating-point number with three decimal places.